# html_nodes return different number of rows (R)

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm new to R and trying to scrape a website. The website contains many products with their prices. When I scrape this, somehow the number of prices exceeds the number of products.

```
library(rvest)
url        <- 'https://website'
webpage    <- read_html(url)
SKU_data   <- html_nodes(webpage,'.title') %>% html_text()
Price_data <- html_nodes(webpage,'.price') %>% html_text()
res        <- data.frame(SKU_data,Price_data)
```

when execute I receive an error

> Error in data.frame(SKU_data, Price_data) : 
>         arguments mean different numbers of lines: 511, 521

The number of products on the website is 511, but there are 521 prices. How can I solve this?

Comment: To solve this I need to receive numeric value from this code

<div class="price"><div class="sbpricestrike"><div class="sbpricestrikeline"></div>1881,-</div><span style="position:relative;">1 699,-<span class="grn">грн.</span></span></div>
                               
                            </div>

Comment: As you can see here are two values, where sometimes first doesn't exist. But I need everytime second. How to get it from there? Then I will have the same 511 values as I have for SKU names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the different lengths, is that the website gives multiple prices for some products. You would want to have the lowest one, right? The lowest price is contained in the element that has `<span style="position:relative;">3 486,-<span class="grn">грн.</span></span>`. Using [Xpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath), you can extract this:

```
 SKU_data    <- html_nodes(webpage,'.title') %>% html_text()

 price_xpath <- "//span[contains(@style, 'position:relative')]"
 Price_data  <- html_nodes(webpage, xpath = price_xpath) %>% 
                   html_text()

 res         <- data.frame(SKU_data, Price_data)
 head(res)                                                                                            
 #    SKU_data                                          Price_data
 # 1  Кресло Чинция Пластик Неаполь N-20                1 699,-грн.
 # 2  Стул Луиза хром Неаполь N-20                        479,-грн.
 # 3  OM-100 Стол письменный (1350х600х750мм) бук/бук     659,-грн.
```

Comment: It is what I need, thanks a lot! Will learn more about XPath because it gives you more power with parsing :)